# get cursor position another form in windows application

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I have two form in my application i am calling two form together from master page.i wrote code in my master page
in top i declared like  this
Dim form As New FrmDelivary
Dim frm1 As New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest

in toolstrip menu event like this:
    Dim frm1 As New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest
    frm1.Location = New Point(625, 225)
    frm1.MdiParent = Me
    frm1.Show()

```
Dim frm2 As New FrmDelivary
frm2.Location = New Point(965, 0)
frm2.MdiParent = Me 
frm.show()
```

if i press R i want to go my cursor the particular textbox of `FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest`

if i press D i want to go my cursor the particular textbox of `FrmDelivary`

How can I do this? i trey something like this in `frmMaster_KeyDown` event: but same page is showing again. I have already open instance of FrmDelivary, so I don't want to show same page again. I want to just get cursor position to particular textbox of this form

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then

    form.Show()
    form.txtTicket.Focus()
    Cursor.Position = form.txtTicket.Location
end if
```

I am working on vb.net windows application

Answer (score 0):

After

```
frm1.Show()
```

place

```
frm1.txtTicket.Focus()
```

I don't think you need the Cursor.Position call

Comment: the same i trayd.  while giving this the particular form is again showing. that particular form instance already opened  .i dont want to open same form again

Answer (score 0):

Set your frm1 and frm2 variables at the top of the code window so they are accessible from all of the Subs.  In your KeyDown event, put

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
    frm1.Show()
    frm1.txtTicket.Focus()
    Cursor.Position = frm1.txtTicket.Location
end if
```

The problem is that you are instantiating a new copy of the form with the "AS NEW frmDelivery" statement.

Comment: i given code like this .but still i am getting new page while entering A