# setting shorcut keys in master form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two form in my application i am calling two form together from master page.i wrote code in my master pager toolstrip menu event like this:

```
Dim frm1 As New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest  
frm1.Location = New Point(625, 225)  
frm1.MdiParent = Me
frm1.Show()
Dim frm2 As New FrmDelivary    
frm2.Location = New Point(965, 0) 
frm2.MdiParent = Me 
frm.show()
```

if i press R i want to go my cursor the particular textbox of FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest
if i press D i want to go my cursor the particular textbox of FrmDelivary
How can I do this? i trey something like this in frmMaster_KeyDown event: but same page is showing again i have already open instance of FrmDelivary ,so i don't want to show same page again . i want to just get cursor position to particular textbox of this form

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then 
    form.Show() 
    form.txtTicket.Focus() 
    Cursor.Position = form.txtTicket.Location 
end if
```

i am working on vb.net windows application.:stackoverflow.com/questions/17918902/… – user2674855 in this link you can able to see my master page design

Comment: Is `form` a valid reference to the created form? Try to exchange `form.Show()` with `form.Activate()`.

Comment: i given code what ever you suggested..but still not getting

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211339/get-cursor-position-another-form-in-windows-application/18212117?noredirect=1#comment26714651_18212117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your code window

```
Dim frm1 As FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest  
Dim frm2 As FrmDelivary
```

In the click event of your toolstrip menu

```
frm1 = New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest  
frm1.Location = New Point(625, 225)  
frm1.MdiParent = Me
frm1.Show()
frm2 = New FrmDelivary    
frm2.Location = New Point(965, 0) 
frm2.MdiParent = Me 
frm2.show()
```

In frmMaster KeyDown (also, make sure frmMaster.KeyPreview is set to True

```
If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.R Then 'revised to include control key
    frm1.Show() 
    frm1.txtTicket.Focus() 
    Cursor.Position = frm1.txtTicket.Location 
end if
'add other keycode events similar to above
```

If you want the quick keys to work in the subforms as well, then set KeyPreview to true for them and add your code for the KeyDown event

Comment: this is working ,,but if i click A that is coming on particular Textbox

Comment: @user2674855 - not sure what you mean by "coming on that particular Textbox"

Comment: if i click shortcut key R in any textbox..this letter coming on that text box

Comment: Well, do you want to be able to type an R or any other shortcut key in the textbox or have it do the form switch?  If you want to make it so it works for, say Ctrl+R instead, which will probably be helpful, then look at the revision above.